# Scrollbar editing in ag-Grid?

Tags: ag-grid, clojurescript

I want the user to edit the cells in the ag-grid, but not in a free text. Is it possible to add a scrollbar, such that the user can select a text from the scrollbar that will be rendered to the cell?

Such as this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible by adding the following to colsDefs

```
{:headerName "Large objects" :field "LO"
                    :cellEditor "agPopupSelectCellEditor"
                    :cellEditorParams {:values ["moon" "sun" "other"]}}
```

Note that

```
:editable true
```

has to be set as well (I put it in the defaultColDefs).